# Runtime Error encountered while taking Screenshot in iMacros

Tags: screenshot, imacros

While taking screenshot of a webpage via iMacros,RuntimeError: SAVEAS requires File IO interface installed is displayed.How to overcome it.

Comment: Did you install file access installer ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use SCREENSHOT funcionality instead of SAVEAS. Use SAVEAS to create a HTML file.
(http://wiki.imacros.net/SCREENSHOT)

I use palemoon version 25.0.0, which can be obtained on (ftp://archive:get@archive.palemoon.org/Pale_Moon/25.x/25.0.0/Palemoon-Portable-25.0.0.win64.exe) - Don't forget to hinder browser ability to auto-update.

Firefox recent versions can´t access file system.

Comment: Even when using the SCREENSHOT functionality it would give the same error: RuntimeError: SCREENSHOT requires File IO interface